# react native ssl pinning

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, ssl

We are building a react native 0.61.4 app and we want to use the library react-native-ssl-pinning. There is a problem with ios certificate and fetch returns error "cancelled" when running on ios.

We have followed the steps from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ssl-pinning .
I am not sure about the step two at Usage ios: 
(skip this if you are using certificate pinning) no extra step needed for public key pinning, AFNetworking will extract the public key from the certificate.

Any thoughts about what might have been wrong?

Comment: If you still haven't managed, try [this article](https://itnext.io/react-native-security-ssl-pinning-cde086210d58). It helped me implement public key pinning quickly on both IOS and Android, using latest React Native version (0.64.2)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [react-native-cert-pinner](https://github.com/approov/react-native-cert-pinner) package for implementing public key pinning in react native. Very easy to install and no need to override fetch method from javascript side. It directly interact with Network layer in iOS.